# Looking for API call to Block Application ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, block

I've been looking all over to find the correct API call to block applications via application ID, however I've yet to find it. I'm actually becoming quite certain that it's not possible (for obvious reasons, Facebook revenue being one of them), however I was wondering if anyone knew of a way, even via URL call ('https://www.facebook.com/apps/block.php?id=' +  APPID + '&action=block' no longer works correctly, if it ever did.)

Basically I've been making a ruby script to be deployed to help users block spammy and generally unwanted applications via application ID's, the script is almost complete, however I need a method to be able to actually block the applications! If anyone could give me some help, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. API wise, there's no "manage_applications" permission (or equivalent), and it makes sense after all, giving apps the ability to remove competitive apps will probably not end nicely.

Comment: I do see what you mean... But I just don't see the point in actually **not** having this ability. It's supposed to be a complete API anyways. Besides, even if a malicious application was trying to block competitive applications they can't do it quietly. It would be required for user intervention at some point (turning). Would it not?

Comment: Users sometimes don't really notice what permissions they grant the app, and so apps will be able to get the permission to block other apps for the users. Also, once one app is doing it, the other apps will do it too, and you get apps war. It's not a legitimate functionality for the api.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#banned

**Create/Ban**

> You can ban a user for an app by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   APP_ID/banned?uid=USER_ID1,USER_ID2 with an application access token
>   (i.e. a token created using the app secret, not an application Page
>   access token as described above). You can specify the following
>   parameters.

Comment: That's not what he asked for, he asked how to ban an app for a user, not how to ban users from an app.

Comment: Thank you Nitzan i just now caught that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not (and probably/hopefully will not ever) possible via API. There are too many reasons to leave it that way. You don't want applications block each other...

This may sounds like a show-stopper for you, but it's not! Generate report arguing the reason why some applications better be blocked/removed/reported and show it to users instructing 'em how to do this.

Comment: This is honestly very helpful to me, _however_ could you please elaborate on:

`You don't want applications block each other...`